# Solving linear system using "reduced row echelon form" when augmented columns is "zero"

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I just learnt about Reduced Row Echelon Form and solved few rather large matrices. However I have no idea how to approach this rather simple system:

$$x+2y=0\\
3x+6y=0$$

Here is my 2x2 augmented matrix:
$$ A = \left[
      \begin{array}{cc|c}
        1&2&0\\
        3&6&0
      \end{array}
    \right]$$

Then I calculated *Reduced Row Echelon Form* by formula $R2 = 3R1 - R2$:
$$ RREF(A) = \left[
      \begin{array}{cc|c}
        1&2&0\\
        0&0&0
      \end{array}
    \right]$$

Now what? I can guess that I have infinite answers because I have zero at last column. However I am not sure about it.

P.S: I am actually trying to find eigenvector of $A=\begin{bmatrix}3&2\\3&8 \end{bmatrix}$. I found $\lambda = 2,9$. Here is my solution to find eigenvector for $\lambda=2$:

$$    \begin{align*}
        (A - \lambda I)\vec{V} &= 0\\
        (\begin{bmatrix}3&2\\3&8\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix})\vec{V} &= 0\\
        \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\3&6\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix} &= \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}\\
        \begin{bmatrix}1x+2y\\3x+6y\end{bmatrix} &= \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}\\
    \end{align*}
$$

Does this means that my matrix have infinite number of eigenvectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing: you do not have infinite answers: this means $x=\infty$, $y=\infty$ which is nonsense.  What you have is **an infinite number of answers**: it is the number of answers that is infinite, not the answers themselves.  (Analogy: "I have a large number of friends on Facebook" is not the same as "I have large friends on Facebook".)

Second thing: whether or not there are an infinite number of answers has nothing to do with the right hand side.  It is because the left hand side includes a non-leading (non-pivot) column.  So you would let the variable corresponding to this column be a parameter, and then solve for the rest in terms of this parameter.

If the zeros on the RHS worry you, start off by solving the following system:
$$\left\{\eqalign{x+2y&=3\cr 3x+6y&=9\ .\cr}\right.$$
Then go back to your question - it is really exactly the same.

See if you can finish the problem.

Re: your PS.  If the matrix $A$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$, then there are **always** an infinite number of eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda$.

Comment: In this case is that correct if I assume $x=1$ and then solve for y to get just one eigenvector for my matrix?

Comment: I suppose it depends what your instructor asks for.  But IMHO it is important to always find **all** eigenvectors.  I have seen many students get very confused when they don't do this.

Comment: Actually I am confused as well. When I ask Maple to give me the Eigenvectors of A, the results are $\begin{bmatrix}2\\9\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}-2&\frac{1}{3}\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$. How come that I get an infinite answer?

Comment: You need to read the Maple documentation and find out what Maple means by this answer.  I don't think it means that $(2,9)$ is an eigenvector.

Comment: You are right. The result Maple provide is totally something else (http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=LinearAlgebra/Eigenvectors). Just last question: Is that correct if we say that we have infinite numbers of eigenvectors for matrix A?

Comment: Yes, see the extra point I added at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct that you have an infinite number of solutions. The reason for this is because the equations are multiples of each other. E2 = 3E1

$$3(x+2y=0)$$
$$3x+6y=0$$

This is true for all systems of equations that are multiples of each other.

For example:

$$2x+4y=8$$
$$6x+12y=24$$

will also have an infinite number of solutions because they're multiples of each other.

Comment: Thank for the answer. I am actually doing this to find an eigenvector of a matrix. Does that mean that my matrix does not have any valid eigenvector?

Comment: I do not recall eigenvectors confidently enough to answer that for you. Though, it is strange that you are doing eigenvectors yet didn't recognize those equations had an infinite number of solutions because they were multiples of each other.

Answer (score 0):

it means that you have only one independent variable and $t(2,-1)$ where $t\in \mathbb R$ is your solution space.